# SQL Join Question

Tags: sql, join

I have the following tables:

Table: user_groups (many-to-many)

- user_id (int)
- group_id (varchar)

Table: profile_groups (many-to-many)

- profile_id (int)
- group_id (varchar)

So basically, I want to write a sql script to find out what profile is assigned to each user.

So in the end there should be only 2 columns: `user_id` and `profile_id`.

How would I go about doing this?

**Edit:** It's actually a lot more complicated than a simple join.

E.g.

User_groups may have the following rows

- 1 group1
- 1 group2
- 1 group3
- 2 group1
- 2 group2
- 3 group4

and profile_groups may have the following:

- 11 group1
- 11 group2
- 11 group3
- 21 group1
- 21 group2
- 22 group4

So the result should be

- 1 11
- 2 21
- 3 22

Each user should only have ONE profile

Comment: Considering your question I think you should in a first time read some tutorials about SQL, like this one http://www.sql.org/sql-database/sql-tutorial/

Comment: Why isn't user 1 also linked to profile 21, through group1 and group2?  Why isn't user 2 linked to profile 11, through group 1 and group2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just saw a question like this the other day.   I think the hard part here is you're looking for user_id/profile_id combinations where the user_id has every group_id that the profile_id has, no more and no less.   So take the usual join and add some correlation to count the number of group_ids each profile/user has and make sure they match (this has been edited a few times):

```
 select user_id, profile_id 
    from user_groups join profile_groups on 
    user_groups.group_id=profile_groups.group_id 
    group by user_id, profile_id
    having count(user_groups.group_id) = 
    (select count(*) from profile_groups as pg where 
    pg.profile_id=profile_groups.profile_id)
    and count(profile_groups.group_id) = (select count(*) from user_groups as ug where 
    ug.user_id=user_groups.user_id)
    ;
```

Here's a run which includes two profiles with three groups each, with one common group between them and a new user in the fourth profile:

```
sqlite>  create table user_groups (user_id integer, group_id varchar);
sqlite>  create table profile_groups (profile_id integer, group_id varchar);
sqlite>  insert into user_groups values(1, 'group1');
sqlite>  insert into user_groups values(1, 'group2');
sqlite>  insert into user_groups values(1, 'group3');
sqlite>  insert into user_groups values(2, 'group1');
sqlite>  insert into user_groups values(2, 'group2');
sqlite>  insert into user_groups values(3, 'group4');
sqlite>  insert into user_groups values(4, 'group1');
sqlite>  insert into user_groups values(4, 'group5');
sqlite>  insert into user_groups values(4, 'group6');
sqlite> 
sqlite>  insert into profile_groups values (11, 'group1');
sqlite>  insert into profile_groups values (11, 'group2');
sqlite>  insert into profile_groups values (11, 'group3');
sqlite> 
sqlite>  insert into profile_groups values (21, 'group1');
sqlite>  insert into profile_groups values (21, 'group2');
sqlite> 
sqlite>  insert into profile_groups values (22, 'group4');
sqlite> 
sqlite>  insert into profile_groups values (23, 'group1');
sqlite>  insert into profile_groups values (23, 'group5');
sqlite>  insert into profile_groups values (23, 'group6');
sqlite>  select user_id, profile_id 
   ...>     from user_groups join profile_groups on 
   ...>     user_groups.group_id=profile_groups.group_id 
   ...>     group by user_id, profile_id
   ...>     having count(user_groups.group_id) = 
   ...>     (select count(*) from profile_groups as pg where 
   ...>     pg.profile_id=profile_groups.profile_id)
   ...>     and count(profile_groups.group_id) = (select count(*) from user_groups as ug where 
   ...>     ug.user_id=user_groups.user_id)
   ...>     ;
1|11
2|21
3|22
4|23
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm trying to achieve. It's getting close to what I want however there is still a problem since it only checks the count rather than the actual groups. So if there are two profiles with 3 groups in each and one group is common between them, the user will come up as having two profiles.

Comment: I'll edit to show my original query which is more complex but seems to address this case.

Comment: the count(table.group_id)'s can each be replaced with count(*), but somehow counting the "group_id" columns seems more intuitive to me.

Comment: That is quite ingenious! Would have took me forever to work that out. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

```
   SELECT ug.user_id, pg.profile_id
     FROM user_groups AS ug
LEFT JOIN profile_groups AS pg
       ON ug.group_id = pg.group_id
```

Answer (score 1):

This will show you a list of users who are associated to profiles:

```
SELECT ug.user_id,
       pg.profile_id
  FROM USER_GROUPS ug
  JOIN PROFILE_GROUPS pg ON pg.group_id = ug.group_id
```

...while this will return a list of all the users, who may be associated to a profile.  If they are not, the `profile_id` column will be `null`:

```
   SELECT ug.user_id,
          pg.profile_id
     FROM USER_GROUPS ug
LEFT JOIN PROFILE_GROUPS pg ON pg.group_id = ug.group_id
```

Keep in mind that because of the relationships being one user_id to many profiles, the `user_id` will likely be displayed multiple times, and possibly duplicates.  For a non duplicated list of data, add the DISTINCT clause or define the GROUP BY clause. IE:

### Using DISTINCT

```
   SELECT DISTINCT
          ug.user_id,
          pg.profile_id
     FROM USER_GROUPS ug
LEFT JOIN PROFILE_GROUPS pg ON pg.group_id = ug.group_id
```

### Using GROUP BY

```
   SELECT ug.user_id,
          pg.profile_id
     FROM USER_GROUPS ug
LEFT JOIN PROFILE_GROUPS pg ON pg.group_id = ug.group_id
 GROUP BY ug.user_id, pg.profile_id
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write that up, I just made some edits to clarify things a little bit. It's actually a lot more complicated than a simple join query.

Comment: @PCBEEF: hsz is correct - my answer covers your updated criteria.

Answer (score 0):

jjia6395, judging from the comments below zzzeek's answer, you want to use the `ALL` operator.
BTW, your question is terribly unclear, the edit didn't help.